# How to send model to layout file from controller in YII2

Tags: layout, model, controller, yii2, parameters

I am not able to send model parameters on layout file via controller action. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add a proprety to your controller

```
public $model;
```

In you controller action

```
$this->model = $model
```

From your layout you can access the model by

```
$this->context->model
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `use` model class in layout file. For eg

```
use app\models\Property; // Property is model name
```

and then in file

```
$prop = Property::findOne($id); // say $id id int > 0
```

You can this model (its properties and method) any way you want